# flex styling fails to add flex-end divs

Tags: angular, flexbox

Home made message bar using css and flex.  The message is supposed to appear on the left (and it does), while the optional buttons should appear on the same bar at the right end (flex end) BUT they wrap to the next line instead of staying on the same line as the message.

[image]

HTML for the component USING the msg bar:

```
<sh-msg-bar [hidden]='isHidden' title='Discard and exit?'
         color="maroon" bcolor="wheat"
         name="sample" brdcolor="beige"
         [buttons]="['Yes', 'No']"
></sh-msg-bar>
```

The msgBar HTML:

```
<div [ngStyle]="{'display': 'flex',
          'flex-direction': 'row',
          'background-color': bcolor,
          'color': color,
          'border-color': brdcolor,
          'border-style': 'solid',
          'border-top-width': '1px',
          'border-left-width': '1px',
          'border-right-width': '3px',
          'border-bottom-width': '3px',
          'height': '30px',
          'width': '100%'}"
 *ngIf="isHidden === false">

  <div *ngIf="isEmpty === false">
      <div [ngStyle]="{'margin': '5px 25px 5px'}">{{title}}</div>
        <div [ngStyle]="{'justify-content': 'flex-end'}">
            <input *ngFor="let nxt of buttons" [ngStyle]="{'margin': '0px 25px 0px'}"
                   type="button" (click)="doBtnEvent(nxt)" value="{{nxt}}">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

MsgBar component code for what it's worth:

```
import {Component, EventEmitter, Input, OnInit, Output} from '@angular/core';

export class btnInfo {
  public text: string;
  public clickFn: string;
}

export class messageInfo {
  public text: string;
  public background: string;
  public timeout: number;  // milliseconds; 0 is none
  public btns: Array<string>; // button labels
}

@Component({
  selector: 'sh-msg-bar',
  templateUrl: './msg-bar.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./msg-bar.component.scss']
})
export class MsgBarComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() name='';
  @Input() title='';
  @Input() color='black';
  @Input() bcolor='white';
  @Input() timeout='0';
  @Input() buttons: Array<string>;
  @Input() brdcolor:'gray';
  @Output() msgEvent = new EventEmitter();
  isHidden = false;
  isEmpty = false;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    if (Number(this.timeout) > 0) {
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.isEmpty = true;
      }, Number(this.timeout));
    }
  }

  toggleHidden() {
    this.isHidden = !this.isHidden;
  }

  doBtnEvent(title: string) {
    console.log(title);
  }
}
```

And I thought I understood flex... LOL.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: It would of been much easier to spot the issue have you posted the output code, `<div *ngIf="isEmpty === false">` is NOT display flex, which means the children of it are not flex items and that's why it wraps. It's just a block div followed by another block div

Comment: Hi,  I'm sorry .. I'm not sure what  more I should have posted... Please clarify.  However, YOUR answer is correct.  If you would like to post it as an answer, I will select it as the correct one. 
Thanks again.

Comment: What I mean is, this issue is strictly html/css, it's better to post the generated markup(html) of your angularjs so it is easier to read

Comment: Did you happen to see why the buttons were not flex-end?  I understand what you would like to have seen .. html/css.  I will do so in the future.

Comment: Answer updated to include the flex end thing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to restructure your container and the content:

```
    <div [ngStyle]="{'display': 'flex',
          'flex-direction': 'row',
          'background-color': bcolor,
          'color': color,
          'border-color': brdcolor,
          'border-style': 'solid',
          'border-top-width': '1px',
          'border-left-width': '1px',
          'border-right-width': '3px',
          'border-bottom-width': '3px',
          'height': '30px',
          'width': '100%'}"
 *ngIf="isHidden === false">

  <div *ngIf="isEmpty === false" [ngStyle]="{'flex': '1 auto' ,'display': 'flex'}">
      <div [ngStyle]="{'margin': '5px 25px 5px',
                       'flex': '1 auto'}">{{title}}</div>
      </div>
      <div [ngStyle]="{}">
            <input *ngFor="let nxt of buttons" [ngStyle]="{'margin': '0px 25px 0px'}"
                   type="button" (click)="doBtnEvent(nxt)" value="{{nxt}}">
      </div>
  </div>
```

Your main container will be `display:flex`, next one with *ngIf="isEmpty === false" will have `flex: 1 auto` to take all his parent space and `display: flex` for its children, the one with the title will have `flex: 1 auto` to take the empty space of his parent and the buttons will have their declared space + margin (so they will stay at the flex-end).

A working code [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-1xptum?file=app%2Fapp.component.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
<div *ngIf="isEmpty === false">
```

is NOT display flex, which means the children of it are not flex items and that's why it wraps. It's just a block div followed by another block div.

You need to add display flex to that div for the children to become flex items. Possibly removing the display flex from the div above it if not needed

To display the message on the left and buttons on the right, you don't need flex-end, just set the flex container to

```
justify-content: space-between;
```

all together

```
<div *ngIf="isEmpty === false" style="display: flex; justify-content: space-between;">
  <div [ngStyle]="{'margin': '5px 25px 5px'}">{{title}}</div>
  <div>
        <input *ngFor="let nxt of buttons" [ngStyle]="{'margin': '0px 25px 0px'}"
               type="button" (click)="doBtnEvent(nxt)" value="{{nxt}}">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Use https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/ as a guide, it helped me when I first started on flex